# Are there other softwares like VNC in Linux like Windows Remote Desktop Connection Tool?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, remote-access, remote-desktop, vnc

Are there other softwares like VNC thats is a remote desktop viewer like VNC but connects to the original screen rather than a virtual one. I m using ubuntu and i would really like to have a tool in ubuntu that will do the work just like windows remote desktop connection

Answer (score 0):

You can consider teamviewer [download linux version here](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx) although it's not quite same way to VNC.